# installation under vmware gets into installation loop

Tags: 12.04, vmware, automation, preseed

I'm instlling Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on VMware servers.
I use preseed to automate the installation.
The problem I have is that once the CD-ROM image is attached to the virtual machine, and the BIOS is configured to pick it first, the machine will always reboot from the CD-ROM even after the previous installation succeeded.
I tried to run "eject" as a preseed/late_command like this:

> d-i preseed/late_command string in-target /media/cdrom/preseed/postinstall.sh; eject

I'm doing it from the late_command line in hope that doing so will mean that the CD-ROM is not kept busy by the postinstall.sh script. But this fails with "illegal IOCTL" and "I/O error" (found this by re-trying the eject from a secondary virtual console after the failure). The CD-ROM is not mounted at this point but still the machine will reboot from the CD-ROM in the next reboot.

I also tried to set:

> d-i cdrom-detect/eject boolean true

but this doesn't change anything either.

Is there an automatic way to tell VMware to behave as if the CD-ROM was ejected for the next reboot?

Right now I'm forced to wait for the reboot and detach the CD-ROM manually at the right moment.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the space bar to exit the loop and continue with the install.

Comment: This would mean that I have to watch the install and hit the space bar at the right time. When it could take any length of time and I have to install multiple servers it becomes a serious burden. I'm looking for an automatic solution.